# Hadoop Split/Regex

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive, hql

I have data that looks like:

```
 Boston--Age:--Gender:--Favorite_Fruit:APPLE--Favorite_Veggie:GREEN BEANS--Blood_Type:AB
```

I would like to split the data to grab the data under Favorite_Veggie without the Blood_Type data:

```
split('Boston--Age:--Gender:--Favorite_Fruit:APPLE--Favorite_Veggie:GREEN 
 BEANS--Blood_Type:AB', 'Favorite_Veggie\\:')[1]
```

current output:

```
 GREEN BEANS--Blood_Type:AB
```

ideal output:

```
 GREEN BEANS
```

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off using `REGEX_EXTRACT`:

```
data = 'Boston--Age:--Gender:--Favorite_Fruit:APPLE--Favorite_Veggie:GREEN BEANS--Blood_Type:AB'

REGEX_EXTRACT(data, 'Favorite_Veggie:([^-]*)', 1)
```

If you want to exclusively use `SPLIT`, then split the first resulting string again:

```
SPLIT(result, '--')[1]
```